# How to simplify coxme survival models?

Tags: r, survival, mixed-model, cox-model

I have some questions about specifying a `coxme` (mixed-effects Cox proportional hazards) model in R and then simplifying it after reading the `coxme` documentation. The situation is this:

I glued 4 pieces of small coral fragments onto small ceramic tiles, which I placed at 4 distances east and west of 10 large coral colonies (i.e. site). Thus, each tile represents one distance-direction-site combination. I checked the small coral fragments daily to see which had died overnight and at the end of the experiment some were still alive (thus, censored). I therefore had 4 fragments per tile*4 distances*2 directions*10 sites = 320 small fragments. Distance and direction are fixed effects, while the tile that each fragment is on and the site are random effects. In addition, each large colony is a different size, so the size of the large colonies should be a random effect, too (`SiteSize`).

The R model I wrote to express this is:

```
mefull<-coxme(Surv(death, censor) ~ Distance*Direction+(1|Site/Tile) +(1|SiteSize))
```

- First, can anyone tell me if this properly specifies the situation I described above?

  After running this model, I found that neither fixed effect nor their interaction was significant. Also, the standard deviation for `Site` and `SiteSize` are identical (~1.12), which seems strange to me. Is there a reason for that? The fact that they are both greater than 1 indicates to me that they contribute a lot of variation to survival. Is that correct?
- My next major question is how to simplify this model. My instinct (and based on reading the manuals and posts here) is to remove each random effect in turn and compare the AICs of the integrated log-likelihood of the resulting models; the model with higher AIC is preferred in this formulation. Is that correct?

  - However, I'd also like to try to simplify the model through removal of the non-significant fixed effects, starting with their interaction. How can I do this while also removing random effects?
  - What terms should I start with removing, or does the order not matter as long as I start with higher-order terms (i.e. interaction)?
  - Can I try as many combinations as I like or do issues with multiple tests come into play?

  Some options are removing one of the random effects (me2) or removing the interaction between the fixed effects but keeping the random effects in place (`me3`).

  ```
  me2<-coxme(surv ~ Distance*Direction+(1|Site/Tile))
  me3<-coxme(surv ~ Distance+Direction+(1|Site/Tile)+(1|SiteSize))
  ```

  When I run these and other combinations of factors, their AIC is always lower than that of the full model, which suggests to me that the full model is best. Any guidance on how to simplify this model would be greatly appreciated.
- Finally, to compare the model with random effects to one without, can I compare the NULL log-likelihood with the integrated log-likelihood? From my understanding of the coxme manual, the one closer to 0 is the better model, so if the integrated one is closer to 0 then the model with random effects is preferred over the one without random effects.

Thanks very much for your time and help.

Comment: Site and SiteSize look like they will be perfectly colinear - each site has one size, right? And they are all different? If so, I don't think you can include both.

Comment: Yes, each site has one size and each site's size is different. So is there any way to account for a potential effect of the variation in the size of the large colonies?

Comment: You essentially have the same variable in your data, twice, only with different names and labels, but the labels are in perfect 1-1 match. So, the answer is that you have already accounted for size in a random effect, along with other ways that colonies vary. However, I think you can include size as a *fixed* effect.